# Как установить сайт в подкаталог другого сайта?

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сайт site.ru, там стоит cms. Нужно поставить другую cms, чтобы она была доступна по адресу site.ru/xxx/
Где что прописать нужно?
Сейчас открывается только так: site.ru/xxx/index.php

Answer (score 1):

В файле `.htaccess`, который расположен (если его там нет - то создаем) в папке `xxx`, делаем (или добавляем) запись

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
```